# Initial zoom level in React Native Maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using `react-native-maps` library.

This is my initial `lat` and `long`,

```
<MapView
   style={{width: '100%', height: 250}}
   initialRegion={{
     latitude: 6.795218101812615,
     longitude: 79.9008869173333,
     latitudeDelta: 6.795218101812615,
     longitudeDelta: 79.9008869173333,
  }}>
```

**But It is not zoomed. Is there any way to set the initial zoom value?**

Image,

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate more on the problem?  The screen shot shows your map.  Are you getting your markers from an API asyncronously?  If so, what do you do then?
You might want to try the `fitMapToBounds` so it will autofit to your map markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `minZoomLevel` prop to give the initial zoom value. You can find more information in [This Link](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)

```
<MapView
   style={{width: '100%', height: 250}}
   minZoomLevel={15}
   initialRegion={{
     latitude: 6.795218101812615,
     longitude: 79.9008869173333,
     latitudeDelta: 6.795218101812615,
     longitudeDelta: 79.9008869173333,
  }}>
```